# How to change text in TextView from event in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm working with Xamarin.Forms in a native PageRenderer (Android) and I implemented Geolocator (https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Geolocator) for use OnPositionChanged event when position is changed. But in the original code they use:

```
    private void OnPositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
            {
                BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                    ListenStatus.Text = e.Position.Timestamp.ToString("G");
                    ListenLatitude.Text = "La: " + e.Position.Latitude.ToString("N4");
                    ListenLongitude.Text = "Lo: " + e.Position.Longitude.ToString("N4");
                });
            }
```

It not work on my app, now I implemented something like that:

```
private void OnPositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
        {
            _activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
                _listenStatus.Text = "Estado:" + e.Position.Timestamp.ToString("G");
                _listenLatitude.Text = "Latitud: " + e.Position.Latitude.ToString("N4");
                _listenLongitude.Text = "Longitud: " + e.Position.Longitude.ToString("N4");
            });
        }
```

When my OnElementChanged is like:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            _activity = this.Context as Activity;
            _activity.SetContentView (Resource.Layout.RequestService);

            _view = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RequestService, this, false);

            AddView (_view);

            SetupElements ();
            SetupGeolocator ();
        }
```

And my SetupElements:

```
void SetupElements ()
        {
            _listenStatus = _view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.ListenStatus);
            _listenLatitude = _view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.ListenLatitude);
            _listenLongitude = _view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.ListenLongitude);
        }
```

But it not working, data is retreiving successfuly, TextViews is loaded sucessfuly and when RunOnUiThread run nothing change in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static Page in your custom renderer to change your views.

Let's say you have a page like:;

```
public class SomePage : ContentPage
{
      public static SomePage ThisPage {get; set;}

      Label label;

      public SomePage()
      {
           ThisPage = this;
           label = new Label();
      }

}
```

And in your page renderer use it like this:

```
SomePage.ThisPage.label.Text = "SomeText";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my live.